# How does a memory map of a 1K EEPROM look like?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, memory, microchip, eeprom

I am using a 1Kbit: The device is organized as one block of 128 x 8-bit memory. I want to understand how to it's organized and how addresses are structured?

Example: I want to store the world "Hello" in the EEPROM. Every character is coded in 1 Byte; So here we have 5 Bytes in total, since the memory is 128 x 8-bit. every character is going to be stored in a address. My question is how these addresses are organized? Is it something like this:

> 0x00: H
> 0x01: E
> 0x02: L
> 0x03: L
> 0x04: O
> ..
> ..
>
> 0x7F

What I am trying to do is to store data in EEPROM in a specif order. So I have to know how memory map looks like in order to know the start and the end address of each field.
Example:
I want to store: name age date of birth and country in an EEPROM. Let's define 2 functions write(address) and read(address). My problem how to determine 'address'?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. Note that the last address will be 0x7F (127) not 128.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here. Are you asking how the data is physically arranged on the chip? Because it can look like anything in a file.

Comment: Thing is, you can organize it however the heck you want, most likely. :)

Comment: In case you're storing some variable length data, like strings of text, you may want to include some way for the reading device to tell how long the stored strings are - either by prefixing it by a byte storing the length, or by suffixing the string with a null byte, the C way.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to store data in EEPROM in a specif order. So I have to know how memory map looks like in order to know the start and the end address of each field.

Comment: Read the freaking data sheet of the device.

Comment: What you mentioned in question is correct. Keep in mind  what @RichardtheSpacecat said!

Answer (score 2):

EEPROMs are usually byte-adressable ie. you simply have an array of bytes. You can set any of them individually (unlike flash, where you can set them bit-by-bit, but erase in larger blocks).

My usual approach when dealing with EEPROMs is to define a structure in the code like:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t magic;
    uint32_t version;
    uint32_t parameter1;
    bool use_something;
    uint8_t parameter2;
    uint32_t checksum;
} settings_t;
```

I declare it in one place (in RAM): `settings_t my_global_settings;`,
then when I want to save it I make `uint8_t` pointer that points to the struct in RAM and then write byte-by-byte in a loop (up to `sizeof(settings_t)`). Reading is done in a similar way.

It is nice to have a file with a memory map of the EEPROM (if you have more than one struct) with defines/constants like EEPROM_CALIBRATION_BASE_ADDR, EEPROM_SETTINGS1_BASE_ADDR etc. You have to calculate the addresses yourself and/or rely on `sizeof`.

Remember to use a checksum, or CRC, or LRC at the end of your data to verify that it actually makes sense.